# CSS selectors above a selector

Tags: css

Is there a way to write css so it would select a div above a selector you already known. 
For example.

```
#modal .container .login{
 //style
}
```

so the above code will look for an ID of modal > classname of container > classname of login.
And style the .login. 
Now is is possible to have it go the reverse. So style the #modal only if it has a child of .login and .container

Thanks

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? no. (in the current CSS spec) as already answered here.
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

but, I can give you a little trick.

create a special CSS rule (a class) with your special styling for the 'parent'.

then, with JQuery, on `document.ready`, check for all the elements in the DOM who meets your requirement (in your case: has a child of some class), and dynamically add the special CSS class.

It's not a perfect solution, but can be helpful in some cases.

Comment: Very good trick but what if the element is invisible and only has the child when a user clicks something else to load the element.

Comment: In the case of dynamic data, more thinking will be needed. but eventually all things can be sorted out and solved. something like: the code who adds the dynamic data also run a check for the dynamic styling.